# How to set UITableViewCell's imageView?

Tags: ios, swift

In the `tableView(tableView:, cellForRowAtIndexPath:) -> UITableViewCell` method, how to set the optional imageView through the cell?

`cell!.imageView?.image = someLoadedImage` in this case, if the `imageView: UIImageView?` property of the `cell` is `nil` when constructed, then the assignment will be failed, right?

According to The "Swift Programming Guide", `john.residence?.address = someAddress`, "In this example, the attempt to set the address property of john.residence will fail, because john.residence is currently nil" (Optional Chaining Chapter).

```
class Residence {
    ...
    var address: Address?
}
class Person {
    var residence: Residence?
}
let john = Person()
let someAddress = Address()
john.residence?.address = someAddress // will fail
```

here is the code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(simpleTableIdentifier)
            as? UITableViewCell
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier)
        }
        let image = UIImage(named: "star")
        let highlightedImage = UIImage(named: "star2")
        cell!.imageView?.image = image // can compile and run
        cell!.imageView?.highlightedImage = highlightedImage

        cell?.textLabel!.text = dwarves[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
```

Comment: What's the real problem?

Comment: the problem is, if assign `cell!.imageView?.image = image`, this should fail? but the app can compile and run. When the cell is initialized, the imageView property should be `nil` right?

Comment: It won't be nil just as cell.textLabel won't be nil. You are using the default cells provided with a table view.If you had a custom cell with a image view in it, it would be nil unless you initialize it.

Comment: Why will this fail? the cell is initialised in `var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(simpleTableIdentifier)
            as? UITableViewCell` and the imageView property will not be `nil`

Comment: Thanks, I was just thinking when constructing a new cell, the `imageView` optional property would be `nil`. If it is not `nil`, does the `imageView` has a placeholder UIImage? I'm relative new to iOS programming.

Comment: are you using a custom cell or the regular one ?

Comment: a regular one, for style: `.Default`

Comment: did you initialize **simpleTableIdentifier** ? and what is at the problem you are having?

Comment: yes, the `simpleTableIdentifier` is just a constant String. if `if cell == nil {...}` is the code to initialize the **default** cell type, then the imageView should have a image in place, right?

Comment: so what is the problem the error you are getting

Comment: there is no error, I was just wondering the reason of setting the image to the imageView property of the cell this way works. The default style of cell has a default UIImage in place? When initializing a UIImageView (`UITableViewCellStyle.Default`), it should be provided with a UIImage, right?

Comment: if the cell is nil it means to there is no reusable cell to be used at this and create a new cell

Comment: If the first time `var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(simpleTableIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell`, `cell` should be nil and goes in to the next block of code to initialize a `.Default` style cell, the `.Default` style cell has a UIImage set? is it `nil` or?

Answer (score 0):

We have reason to check if the cell is nil because if there is no available reusable cell for us in the queue to use at this time we have to create a new one.

Comment: yes, but this will not work: `let imageview = UIImageView(image: image, highlightedImage: highlightedImage);
        cell!.imageView = imageview` After the cell is initialized using `.Default` style